# Is it possible to order questions by votes and filter them by asking date?

Tags: feature-request, questions, sorting, filtering

I have the habit of browsing the top 5000 most voted questions. That means 100 pages of 50 questions per page. This long process spans many days, even weeks, and while my browser keeps track of the open tabs/windows I often see questions shift on a certain page due to "newcoming" questions.

Could there be a feature to filter by asking date and order by votes?

Answer (score 3):

Lots of information here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching

In general, you can find the questions created within a date range by searching for `created:{startdate}..{enddate}`, e.g.,

```
created:2018-04-23..2018-04-24
```

If you just want one date

```
created:2018-04-23
```

There's also a shortcut for "yesterday"

```
created:1d
```

*(Note that times are recorded in UTC.)*

All search results pages have the ability to sort by relevance (default), newest, **votes**, and active. Simply click on the appropriate tab. (Unfortunately, the choice doesn't "stick" between searches.)

Example: [Questions created on New Years Day sorted by votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=created%3a2018-01-01+is%3Aq)